# sqlserver+php: get just inserted row id

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I tried this way:

```
$result = odbc_exec($connection, 'SELECT id FROM MyTable WHERE id = @@Identity');
```

but it gives me

> syntax error: unexpected T_VARIABLE

**edit: here's complete logic thanks to your help:**

```
$result = odbc_exec($connection, 'INSERT data into the table;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id;');
$row = odbc_fetch_array($result); //this line gives the error!
$id = $row['id'];
```

**edit2: I missed a ";" =_=**

Anyway scope_identity does not work: gives

> no tuples available at this index

on fetcharray call

Comment: Well of course `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` doesn't work in the code you are showing. `SCOPE` is an important part of that word - you need to call `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` immediately after, and in the *same scope*, as the `INSERT`. Like I showed in my answer (and like I'm sure @Andomar meant).

Answer (score 1):

After inserting a row, you can look up the last inserted id using `scope_identity()`.  There's no need to look it up in the original table:

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTIY()
```

If the row was inserted on another connection, you can query the maximum value of `id`:

```
SELECT max(id) FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Be very careful about the `max` query. How do you know that is the id that was inserted by a specific connection?

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you just saying:

```
$result = obdc_exec('INSERT dbo.MyTable(...) VALUES(...); SELECT id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();');
```

Or better yet, put the logic into a stored procedure and stop burying ad hoc SQL in your application code.

**EDIT** because PHP is weird and may treat your INSERT as a resultset, you may need to play with this (pardon me, but I am not a PHP expert):

```
odbc_next_result($result);
```

You may also be able to suppress the first result by saying:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON; INSERT ...; SELECT id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Again, I don't know, I don't do PHP. I still think you should be doing this in a stored procedure.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but there's to be something on obtaining the query result..edited the first post!

Comment: You are probably missing a curly brace or bracket somewhere. We can't tell because you didn't show the surrounding code.